# how come my back ground image is placed over all my objects java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, bufferedimage

I am working on an ice hockey game and my background image is being displayed over top of the objects(puck and 2 players) I know that all the objects are there because I can hear the music play when the puck hits one of the paddles

```
//in Game_Panel class
private BufferedImage img;
Game_Panel(BufferedImage img){

        this.image = img;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new AL());

        newPlayer();
        newOpponent();
        newPuck();
        score = new Score(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
        new Music("Music/background.wav").playBackground();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }
```

```
//in Game_Frame calss
  private BufferedImage img;
       Game_Frame(){
           importImg();
        
        panel = new Game_Panel(img);
        this.add(panel);

        this.setTitle("Air Hockey");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private void importImg() {

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("GameImage/rink.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't override paint in JComponents. Override paintComponent

Comment: Don't use threads like you are doing to create a game loop. Instead use javax.swing.Timer

Comment: See [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). `KeyListener`s are bad news, use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Comment: q: *"how come my back ground image is placed over all my objects java swing"*? a: `super.paintComponent(g);` paints all your "objects", then `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);` overwrites everything with the background image... Swap the order. *And* override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, as @ControlAltDel says.